Attach hyperlink automatically for matched keywords
I've installed the CKEditor5 plugin in my strapi project. What I would like to do know is that when I'm typing the word Google in the editor, it will automatically attached to https://www.google.com instead of doing it manually by clicking on the link and enter the url.
What I've done so far is by adding the typingconfig in the ckeditor.txt file under the config folder but it doesn't support this feature. Is there any other ways to do so?
    typing: {
        transformations: {
          include: [
              'quotes',
              'typography',
              'symbols',
              'mathematical',
              // Plus, some custom transformation.
              { from: 'CKE', to: 'CKEditor' },
              { from: 'Google', to: '<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>'} //this won't work
          ],
        },

